# How can I get the decision path to specific class type in classification decision tree

Tags: matlab, classification, instantiation, decision-tree, data-generation

Let's say I have created a classification decision tree as following:

```matlab
HP(1:size(HP), end) = 0; LP(1:size(LP), end) = 1;
% the dt's input & target pop
x = [HP(:,1:end-1); LP(:,1:end-1)]; t = [HP(:,end); LP(:,end)];
dt = fitctree(x,t);
view(dt)
view(dt, 'mode', 'graph');
```

And the outputs are as below:

```
1  if x2<-21.4866 then node 2 elseif x2>=-21.4866 then node 3 else 1
2  class = 1
3  if x2<20.093 then node 4 elseif x2>=20.093 then node 5 else 0
4  if x1<27.8438 then node 6 elseif x1>=27.8438 then node 7 else 0
5  if x2<39.6866 then node 8 elseif x2>=39.6866 then node 9 else 1
6  if x1<-33.7504 then node 10 elseif x1>=-33.7504 then node 11 else 0
7  class = 1
8  class = 1
9  class = 0
10  class = 1
11  if x2<1.53772 then node 12 elseif x2>=1.53772 then node 13 else 0
12  if x2<-2.50063 then node 14 elseif x2>=-2.50063 then node 15 else 0
13  class = 0
14  if x1<14.2153 then node 16 elseif x1>=14.2153 then node 17 else 0
15  class = 1
16  class = 0
17  class = 1
```

And

[image]

## *Question*:

1) How can I get all the paths which leads to leafs with value of '0'?

2) Is there any **delicate** way to create new instances based on a decision tree(other than randomly generat instance and loop until the desired output)? for example I want to create a **random** instance which the above tree classifies it as '0'

Answer (score 0):

If you know the end node of the decision, you can find the path. and you can get end node number from `[lable, score, node, cusum] = predict(mdl,x);`. If you would like to get node for each tree from Treebagger then you need run the same in a loop for each tree. `[lable, score, node, cusum] = mdl.Trees{i}.predict(x);`